# Having UserControl signing up for event in MainForm

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am currently working on a Winforms solution where I have a Main Form containing a `ToolStrip` and a Panel. The solution is meant as an administrative tool.
The panel is filled with a user control, normally containing an input form or a `ListView` of some sort.
Depending on which button is clicked the user control in the Panel is replaced with another user control.

So far so good. Now the trickier part is that the user can be administrator of one or more departments, and if the user is admin of more than one departments, some of the user controls will be displaying a `ComboBox` where the admin can choose which department to admin. However some of the user controls are independent of the department and therefore does not contain the `ComboBox`.

Now the thing is that instead of adding the `ComboBox` to the user control that are department-specific I have been thinking about adding it to the Main Form and have the user controls, when instantiated, look at what department is picked and populate the data accordingly.
But my problem is: When a user then is picking another department in the `ComboBox` I will have to tell the child (user control) that the value has changed.

My first thought was to have the user control - when instantiated - sign up for the change-event. But that I can not seem to figure out how to get working (it is easier going the other way around).
Another approach that I have been thinking about is to call a method in the user control from the Main Form whenever the value has changed. However there will be no guarantee that such method exists as not all user controls need this functionality.

Is there a preferred/golden solution to this? Something I am missing or is this just bad practice/design?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When childcontrols needs to be notified, i would implement an Interface. You should avoid crosscalling methods/event handling because events could lead to "ghost controls" and unreadable code.

I would do something like this:   (pseudo/not tested)

```
public interface IDepartmentChanged
{
   void DepartmentChanged(int departmentId);
}


public class UserControl1 : UserControl, IDepartmentChanged
{
    public void DepartmentChanged(int departmentId)
    {
      // refresh data
    }
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
   // Add all UserControls to a List  => _controls 
   private List<UserControl> _controls = new List<UserControl>();

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _controls.Add(userControl11);
   }

   private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        int selectedDepartmentId = ((MyData)comboBox1.SelectedValue).Id;

        foreach (UserControl control in _controls)
            if (control is IDepartmentChanged)
                ((IDepartmentChanged)control).DepartmentChanged(selectedDepartmentId);

        // or even shorter:
        foreach (IDepartmentChanged departmentChanged in _controls.OfType<IDepartmentChanged>())
            departmentChanged.DepartmentChanged(selectedDepartmentId);
   }
```

On this method the childs functionality is totally separated from the parent.(OOP)

Comment: I have ended up using this solution. This way I will not have to add and remove event handlers whenever the current user control changes. Plus I wanted a generic solution that was able to find out for itself.

Answer (score 1):

i created a form and a user`enter code here`Control (called `UserControl1`) and added it to the form. i've added a `comboBox` to the form and then did:

```
 public Form1()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += userControl11.comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
 }
```

and then when the `comboBox1` the user control knows about it and can re initiate

Comment: Thanks. I can not see how I could not think of that. You just made my day.